# best practice to store the lookup no match output in SSIS

Tags: ssis-2012

which is the best practice to store the lookup no match output in SSIS ? OLEDB Destination or some file system. I have been asked to keep track of those no match record, but i need to come up with the decision of what medium would be the best for storing those No match Record.
Thanks in advance for Sharing your Valuable Experience with me..!

Comment: Medium means : Either filesystem or in OLE DB Destination

Answer (score 0):

Storing it in a SQL table will be your best solution as it is much easier to keep track on all the historical mismatches.Make sure you are creating some kind of a process Id and time-stamp to be able to relate each mismatch to the point of time it occured. If you are looking for a simple example try [this](http://www.rad.pasfu.com/index.php?/archives/46-SSIS-Upsert-With-Lookup-Transform.html).